# listview на WF и listview на WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Есть простенькая программка на WF, которая ищет wifi сети и подключается к ним. Состоит из ListView, двух кнопок, двух лейблов и текстбокса для ввода пароля:.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wifi = new Wifi();
    List<AccessPoint> aps = wifi.GetAccessPoints();

    foreach (AccessPoint ap in aps)
    {
        ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem(ap.Name);
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(ap.SignalStrength + "%");
        lvItem.Tag = ap;

        listNet.Items.Add(lvItem);
    }
}

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listNet.SelectedItems.Count > 0 && textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        ListViewItem selectedItem = listNet.SelectedItems[0];

        AccessPoint ap = (AccessPoint)selectedItem.Tag;

        if (connectToWifi(ap, textBox1.Text))
            label2.Text = "Есть контакт " + ap.Name;
        else
            label2.Text = "Пробуй еще";
    }
    else
        label2.Text = "Введи пароль";
}
```

Решил переделать ее на WPF, и вылезают ошибки в этих местах:
Ошибка в `new ListViewItem` и `SubItems`

```
 ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem(ap.Name);
 lvItem.SubItems.Add(ap.SignalStrength + "%");
```

А так же в `listNet.SelectedItems[0];`:

```
 ListViewItem selectedItem = listNet.SelectedItems[0];
```

В WPF я не силен, подскажите как правильно это переписать?

Comment: Правильно - научится использовать привязки и не использовать контролы из кода. Иначе, я вам не советую переходить на WPF и сидеть дальше на WinForms!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ справедливости ради, в WinForms тоже есть привязки, хотя и не у всех контролов. Но, по неведомой мне причине, про них мало, что написано в книгах (у Петцольда этому посвящена одна глава) и начинающих совсем не обучают их использовать.

Comment: @Bulson А я и не говорю, что их там нет. Просто как по мне, подход автора все еще актуален в старом добром WinForms, но в WPF это совершенно не уместно и наоборот добавит уйму проблем.

Comment: В WPF контролы создаются в коде xaml, где вы описываете ГУЙ. Из кода создавать контроля противопоказано. Далее, создаёте в коде геттеры/сеттеры свойств для контроля, и в xaml с помощью Binding привязываете их. Класс для сеттеров должен быть отдельный. А лучше посмотреть простенький пример для начала.